# How to approximate the result of a sum to the value of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame:

```
data = {'id':[xxx, xxy, xxz, xyx, xzy],
        'Total_I':[4796.6, 170637.53, 782.64, 449.12, 25654.02],
        'SumImp_RP':[3658.75, 0, 0, 0, 21530.45],
        'Total_E':[1137.84, 170637.56, 1565.26, 449.11, 8501.18],
        'Egre_E':[980.9, 130901.29, 674.69, 387.17, 1532.76],
        'ImpEgre_E':[156.94, 20944.27, 107.94000000000001, 61.94, 245.24],
        'Desc_E':[1137.84, 151845.56, 782.63, 449.11, 1778], 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With the following code I obtain the balance and balance2.

```
dfLim[["Desc_E", "Total_E", "Total_I", "SumImp_RP"]] = dfLim[["Desc_E", "Total_E", "Total_I", "SumImp_RP"]].astype(float)

dfLim['SalIns2'] = dfLim.loc[(dfLim.Desc_E< dfLim.Total_E)                                   & dfLim.TotalEgresos_E <= dfLim.Total_I) & ((dfLim.SumImp_RP + dfLim.TotalEgresos_E) <= dfLim.Total_I)].eval('(Total_E + SumImp_RP) - Total_I')

dfLim['SalIns'] = (dfLim.Total_I - (dfLim.SumImp_RP + dfLim.Desc_E))
```

I get the following result:

| id | Total_I | SumImp_RP | Total_E | Egre_E | ImpEgre_E | Desc_E | SalIns2 | SalIns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | 4796.6 | 3658.75 | 1137.84 | 980.9 | 156.94 | 1137.84 |  | 0.01 |
| xxy | 170637.53 | 0 | 170637.56 | 130901.29 | 20944.27 | 151845.56 |  | 18791.97 |
| xxz | 782.64 | 0 | 1565.26 | 674.69 | 107.94 | 782.63 |  | 0.01 |
| xyx | 449.12 | 0 | 449.11 | 387.17 | 61.94 | 449.11 |  | 0.01 |
| xzy | 25654.02 | 21530.45 | 8501.18 | 1532.76 | 245.24 | 1778 |  | 2345.57 |

But this is not what I'm totally looking for, I would like to find a way to get Total_E as close to Total_I as possible, since sometimes Total_E may be greater than Total_I, which is also correct.

Also if I could get SalIns and SalIns2 in a single column it would be very nice.

I have tried something like the following but nothing works for me:

```
dfLim['diff'] = abs((dfLim['SumImp_RP'] + dfLim['Total_E ']) - dfLim['Total_I'])

mask = (dfLim['Desc_E'] < dfLim['Total_E ']) & \
       (dfLim['Total_E '] <= dfLim['Total_I']) & \
       (dfLim['diff'] <= 0.1)

dfLim['SalIns2'] = dfLim.loc[mask].eval('(Total_E + SumImp_RP) - Total_I')

dfLim = dfLim.drop(columns=['diff'])
```

This part also generates the same result for me.

This is the result I expect:

| id | Total_I | SumImp_RP | Total_E | Egre_E | ImpEgre_E | Desc_E | SalIns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx | 4796.6 | 3658.75 | 1137.84 | 980.9 | 156.94 | 1137.84 | 0.01 |
| xxy | 170637.53 | 0 | 170637.56 | 130901.29 | 20944.27 | 151845.56 | -0.03 |
| xxz | 782.64 | 0 | 1565.26 | 674.69 | 107.94 | 782.63 | 0.01 |
| xyx | 449.12 | 0 | 449.11 | 387.17 | 61.94 | 449.11 | 0.01 |
| xzy | 25654.02 | 21530.45 | 8501.18 | 1532.76 | 245.24 | 1778 | 2345.57 |

Comment: Can you explain your logic please?

Comment: It is a matter of a sum, as long as it meets certain criteria, since sometimes Total_E is equal to Total_I so all of the above is unnecessary. @corralien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test some combinations and keep those minimize the difference:

```
# Scenarios
bal0 = dfLim['Total_I'] - dfLim['Total_E']
bal1 = dfLim['Total_I'] - dfLim['SumImp_RP'] - dfLim['Total_E']
bal2 = dfLim['Total_I'] - dfLim['SumImp_RP'] - dfLim['Desc_E']

# Go to numpy, same as bal = np.stack([bal0, bal1, bal2], axis=1) 
bal = pd.concat([bal0, bal1, bal2], axis=1).to_numpy()

# Extract the min index value (== 0)
dfLim['SalIns'] = bal[abs(bal).argsort() == 0]
```

Output:

```
    id    Total_I  SumImp_RP    Total_E     Egre_E  ImpEgre_E     Desc_E   SalIns
0  xxx    4796.60    3658.75    1137.84     980.90     156.94    1137.84     0.01
1  xxy  170637.53       0.00  170637.56  130901.29   20944.27  151845.56    -0.03
2  xxz     782.64       0.00    1565.26     674.69     107.94     782.63     0.01
3  xyx     449.12       0.00     449.11     387.17      61.94     449.11     0.01
4  xzy   25654.02   21530.45    8501.18    1532.76     245.24    1778.00  2345.57
```

Comment: It has helped me a lot to obtain the results I wanted, I also had other scenarios that I included in the code. But it worked anyway. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please? Now, you can add any other scenarios/combinations you have. If you have many columns, you can use a LP solver to find the sum that minimize the difference.

Comment: The first answer really helped me with everything I needed. But I try it anyway. thank you so much